# Google Calendar Erroneously Deleting Events

Tags: google-calendar

Over the last couple of weeks, Google calendar has repeatedly deleted the events I entered. It occurs approximately 12-24 hours after I create the event.

EDIT: In response to question below, it's deleting events created both on the phone, as well as at calendar.google.com.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? If so, has anyone had luck fixing it?

Finally, does anyone know how I can contact Google directly about this issue? Their "help" page is a labyrinth.

Devices: Sprint HTC EVO 4G, Android v. 2.3.5
Macbook OSX 10.6.8

Comment: is it deleting events created on your phone or via calendar.google.com?

Comment: @jlehenbauer, it's deleting both.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is validation? Try changing your Gmail password and logging back into the apps on your computer an phone.

Comment: Thanks @jlehenbauer, what should that accomplish?

Comment: Eliminating the ability of anything that's potentially accessing your account and erasing those entries, like apps or services. Really it's just a precautionary initial measure.

Comment: @jlehenbauer - got it. that makes a lot of sense. is there a way to check which apps have access to my calendar?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3957/discussion-between-jlehenbauer-and-adam-g)

Comment: Did you solve the issue -- and if so, how? Feel free to answer your own question, as it might help others encountering a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Spanning](https://freetools.spanning.com/#undelete), which was perfect. Took care of the whole thing. Why google doesn't have this functionality is beyond me.